# Extract common factor

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

```
Example: g[x_] = (x^3 - 27)/((x - 3)*(x + 1))
```

Here the common factor is x-3, how can i extract that common factor from a function (g(x)) and put it as a separate ..

```
Example: f[x] = x-3
```

Comment: `f[x_] = Numerator[g[x]]/Numerator[g[x] // Cancel] // Cancel`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [`PolynomialGCD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialGCD.html) is the most direct tool:

```
g[x_] = (x^3 - 27)/((x - 3)*(x + 1));

PolynomialGCD @@ Through @ {Numerator,Denominator} @ g[x]
```

> -3+x

If you don't like operator notation, you might find this version preferable:

```
With[{n = Numerator[g[x]], d = Denominator[g[x]]}, PolynomialGCD[n,d]]
```

> -3+x

Comment: May I ask why you enclosed your second example in a With statement? E.g., what about just: `PolynomialGCD[Numerator[g[x_]], Denominator[g[x_]]]`?